# Price on application - Magento 1.9.1 RWD theme?

Tags: magento-1.9

Anyone using the rwd theme from 1.9.1 and have price on application (call for pricing) working?

I've followed this guide to no avail: http://www.webamondo.co.uk/blog/magento-1-9-poa/

Pulling my hair out trying to figure this out..

So basically, POA allows me to set items to "call for pricing" via an attribute... This worked in my previous build of magento 1.4 in which anything set with the attribute "call for pricing" hid the add to cart button, along with the price tag for the item, and instead displayed "call for pricing" in its place.

What's happening when I follow that guide is on the product grid display page, I get the following error under the first item "Fatal error: Call to a member function getSource() on a non-object in /**/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product.php on line 1385"

Here's the chunk of code for lines 1375 - 1387

```
/**
 * Get attribute text by its code
 *
 * @param $attributeCode Code of the attribute
 * @return string
 */
public function getAttributeText($attributeCode)
{
    return $this->getResource()
        ->getAttribute($attributeCode)
            ->getSource()
                ->getOptionText($this->getData($attributeCode));
}
```

Here's what it looks like on the frontend - imgur.com/zLB1uJc,FjUvgFi The first image is the error on my 1.9.1 build w/ RWD template.. The second is it working on my old 1.4 build.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Please explain what you want to achieve and what doesn't work as expected. Maybe add a few screenshots to make it more clear

Comment: Yes, please update with specific issues.

Comment: Make sure your attribute "poa" exists (under Catalog=>Manage Attributes.) The example you linked is trying to load the attribute_code: 'poa'. Is this identical to your own attribute's attribute_code?
(For this Fatal Error to happen, most probably $attributeCode is not set, or the attribute it is trying to get doesn't exist.)